# Pester reset test data

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, pester

This is about scope of test data in pester. I am testing a function `Add-HashTableIfNotPresent` which checks for the existence of a key in a hashtable, if it doesn't exist it adds it otherwise it returns the value linked to that key.

I have 2 `It` blocks for my pester test that check the 2 scenarios - key exists and key doesn't exist. I was expecting `$ht` to be recreated for each `It` block but it's not so if I swap the order of my 2 `It`s then `Returns existing entry when passed existing key` fails because `$ht.count` is still 3.

Is there a way to get `$ht` reset for each test or do I need to define it inside the `It` block?

Function under test:

```
function Add-HashTableIfNotPresent {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [hashtable] $sourceTable,
        [string] $keyToCheck
    )

    $subTable = $sourceTable.$keyToCheck
    if(-not $subTable){
        $subTable = @{}
        $sourceTable.$keyToCheck = $subTable
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
Describe 'Add-HashTableIfNotPresent' {
    $ht = @{
        subTable1 = @{
            st1 = "abc"
        }
        subTable2 = @{
            st2 = "def"
        }
    }

    It "Returns existing entry when passed existing key" {
        Add-HashTableIfNotPresent -sourceTable $ht -keyToCheck subTable2
        $ht.Count | Should BeExactly 2
        $value = $ht.subTable2
        $value.count | Should BeExactly 1
        $value.st2 | Should -Be "def"
    }

    It "Adds entry that doesn't exist" {
        Add-HashTableIfNotPresent -sourceTable $ht -keyToCheck subTable3
        $ht.Count | Should BeExactly 3
        $addedValue = $ht.subTable3
        $addedValue | Should -Be $true
        $addedValue.count | Should BeExactly 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Context` and `Describe` blocks have scopes that mean variables defined in them are restricted to that specific block and don't exist outside it, but your variables still aren't then automatically reset for each `It` test.

I would suggest using a Function to set your hashtable before each test:

```
Function Set-TestHashTable {
    @{
        subTable1 = @{
            st1 = "abc"
        }
        subTable2 = @{
            st2 = "def"
        }
    }
}

Describe 'Add-HashTableIfNotPresent' {

    $ht = Set-TestHashTable

    It "Returns existing entry when passed existing key" {
        Add-HashTableIfNotPresent -sourceTable $ht -keyToCheck subTable2
        $ht.Count | Should BeExactly 2
        $value = $ht.subTable2
        $value.count | Should BeExactly 1
        $value.st2 | Should -Be "def"
    }

    $ht = Set-TestHashTable

    It "Adds entry that doesn't exist" {
        Add-HashTableIfNotPresent -sourceTable $ht -keyToCheck subTable3
        $ht.Count | Should BeExactly 3
        $addedValue = $ht.subTable3
        $addedValue | Should -Be $true
        $addedValue.count | Should BeExactly 0
    }
}
```